# How to check all rules which can be applied to a mailItem in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, mailitem

I am writing an application which has to get items that can be matched with rules.

```
//new messages goes here
void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
    {
        //all rules
        Rules rules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules();

        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;

        if (mail != null)
        {
            // I need to find out if mail matches with one of the rule. And handle in an appropriate way.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to check which rules apply to which items is by enumerating the [**Rule Conditions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff867147.aspx) (*and [excluding rule exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff867239)*) manually for each `MailItem`. The rule engine works by executing each rule you have defined via [`Rule.Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff864433.aspx) - it doesn't provide a mechanism to preview affected items.

Here is an (*untested*) example for reference on how to match a **contains subject rule** (`olConditionSubject`). You would also need to handle [other Rule Conditions types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869540.aspx).

```
if (mail != null)
{
    foreach (Outlook.Rule rule in rules)
    {
       foreach (Outlook.RuleCondition condition in rule.Conditions)
       {
         if (condition is TextRuleCondition)
         {
            Outlook.TextRuleCondition trc = condition as Outlook.TextRuleCondition;
            if (trc.ConditionType == Outlook.OlRuleConditionType.olConditionSubject)
            {
              // TODO: handle Rule.Exceptions conditions
              bool containsSubject = mail.Subject.Contains(trc.Text);
            }
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do to the complexities of the `Rule Conditions` - you will have to go through each condition you want to support 1-by-1. I can add one example for reference.

Comment: See above example - you may also want to check if the rule is enabled [`Rule.Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868097.aspx) and follow rule execution order [`Rule.ExecutionOrder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff860647.aspx)

Comment: Can I somehow to iterate through all rule.Conditions? or I need to write a lot of code for a particular case.